# Sorting different numbers into equal stacks

Tags: matlab, sorting

Hello I'm sort of new to matlab but I am working on a program that will take a bunch of numbers (prices) and sort them into groups that have near the same or near equivalent value (equal cost). However I'm not sure how to program that... does this already exist? If not how should I go about sorting these items.

Ex. sort 3 4 4 4 5 6 7 into 4 piles. 33/4 = 8.25 = Avg

Piles are 7 (4+4) (3+6) (4+5) or 7 8 9 9

Obviously these would also have two decimal places behind them (3.XX) any ideas?

Comment: This is called the [partition problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_problem).

Comment: And it's (computationally) hard